# Pyspark select multiple columns from list and filter on different values

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have a table with ~5k columns and ~1 M rows that looks like this:

| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 | Col8 | Col9 | Col10 | Col11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| ID2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| ID3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| ID4 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| ID5 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I want to select different columns matching column names from different lists and subset the rows according to different criteria. For example if my list1 has col1, col3, col4, col11 and list2 has col2, col6, col9, col10. I want to filter rows as list1 == 0 AND list2 == 1. E.g  `df1 = df.filter((df.col1 == 0) & (df.col3 == 0) & (df.col4 == 0) & (df.col6== 1) & (df.col9 == 1) & (df.col10 == 1))` . Instead of adding column name each time, I want these columns to be selected from two different lists.  How can I achieve this using PySpark?

Comment: Does `list1 == 0` mean that all values for all selected columns are `0`? Anyway, it looks quite simple: select columns + filter on desired values on all or part of the columns... or did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, all matching columns in list 1 should have value of 0 and all matching columns in list 2 should have value 1. I am confused how to filter on two or more different criteria.  E.g  `df1 = df.filter((df.col1 == 0) & (df.col3 == 0) & (df.col4 == 0) & (df.col6== 1) & (df.col9 == 1) & (df.col10 == 1))` .  Instead of adding column name each time, I want these columns to be selected from two different lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution that I was looking for:
I was able to filter large number of columns using following steps:

1. Created separate lists with column IDs. My column IDs were in a Dataframe. So I converted the column to list for filtration process.

```
list1 = ped.filter((ped.pheno == 2)).select("IID")
list1 = list1.select('IID').rdd.map(lambda row : row [0]).collect()`
list2 = ped.filter((ped.pheno == 1)).select("IID")
list2 = list2.select('IID').rdd.map(lambda row : row [0]).collect()

## 2. Using these lists I filtered the columns as follows:

df1 = df.where ("AND".join([(%s ==1)"%(col) for col in list1]))
df1 = df.where ("AND".join([(%s ==0)"%(col) for col in list2]))
```

Thanks for other helpful solutions as well!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to compare a lot of columns like this consider tuple-wise comparisons like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, struct
source_tuple = struct(col("col1"), col("col3"), col("col4"), col("col6"), col("col9"), col("col10"))
target_tuple1 = struct([lit(0), lit(0), lit(0), lit(1), lit(1), lit(1)])
df1 = df.where(source_tuple.isin([target_tuple1]))
```

You can build the left and right sides dynamically and add multiple tuples to the right-hand side. If you need multiple left-hand sides combine the resulting DataFrames using UNION ALL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, This worked for me

```
tmp_cols = ['col1','col2']
filter_conditions = [col(c) ==1 for c in tmp_cols]
nestor = lambda u, v : (u) | (v)
df = df.filter(reduce(nestor, filter_conditions))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).